# Import данных с Word Form в Excel | Макрос

Tags: excel, visual-basic, ms-word, макросы, макрос

Есть проблема следующего характера:
Есть макрос для импорта данных с Word Form в Excel,но дело в том что он импортирует только текстовые значение,  а в форме присутствуют так же так называемые checkbox-сы, и после импорта в таблице Excel они отображаются одинаково не в зависимости он того был выбран данный check box или же нет.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Все материалы прикрепляю к данному посту.

```
Sub GetFormData()
     'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim FmFld As Word.FormField
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
    i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        i = i + 1
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        With wdDoc
            j = 0
            For Each FmFld In .FormFields
                j = j + 1
                WkSht.Cells(i, j) = FmFld.Range.Text
            Next
        End With
        wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

[image: Файл Word Form]
[image: Файл Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Замените фрагмент Вашего кода

```
With wdDoc
    j = 0
    For Each FmFld In .FormFields
        j = j + 1
        If FmFld.Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = Format(FmFld.CheckBox.Value, "Yes/No") ' Нужное значение
        Else
            WkSht.Cells(i, j) = FmFld.Range.Text
        End If
    Next
End With
```